# Azure VM: auto-shutdown not working if email notification is enabled

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm having some problems getting the auto-shutdown feature for a VM to work when I enable the email notification feature as shown int the following image:

[image: Auto-shutdonw schedule]

If I remove the Send notification option, then the machine will be shutdown. However, if I active the notification, I won't receive any email and the machine won't be shutdown.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? On my side, it works as expected. But there is one thing you need to take care of. When you enable the auto-shutdown and set the notification with an e-mail, the **Scheduled shutdown** time should be later than the current time at least half an hour.

Here is the example on my side:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Charles. Yes, I've done that test also, but it's not working...whnever there's an email, it refuses to shutdown or send an email...

Comment: @LuisAbreu When do you set the auto-shutdown?

Comment: I've tried setting it during creation and after it's been created...shutdown was always set (at least) 2h after the current time (I' have used my timezone for reference)...Unfortunately, and as I said, whenever I enter an email, it won't do anything.

Comment: @LuisAbreu That's so wired. All things work fine on my side.

Comment: I know...not sure if it's important, but I'm using one of those dev accounts that's available from MSDN subscription...Any ideas on what I can do test this?

Comment: @LuisAbreu As I know there are no things important. I also do not know why. Perhaps the permission?